# How to create DataFrame from XLSX.readdata() object with header?

Tags: dataframe, julia, xlsx

I am trying to create DataFrame Object as follows:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> using XLSX

julia> T = XLSX.readdata("zillow_data_download_april2020.xlsx", #filename,
           "Sale_counts_city", #sheet name,
           "A1:F9" #cell range,
           )
9×6 Array{Any,2}:
      "RegionID"  "RegionName"    "StateName"      "SizeRank"      "2008-03"      "2008-04"
  6181            "New York"      "New York"      1                missing        missing
 12447            "Los Angeles"   "California"    2            1446           1705
 39051            "Houston"       "Texas"         3            2926           3121
 17426            "Chicago"       "Illinois"      4            2910           3022
  6915            "San Antonio"   "Texas"         5            1479           1529
 13271            "Philadelphia"  "Pennsylvania"  6            1609           1795
 40326            "Phoenix"       "Arizona"       7            1310           1519
 18959            "Las Vegas"     "Nevada"        8            1618           1856
    
julia> typeof(T)
Array{Any,2}
```

Header becomes part of data:

```
julia> DataFrame(T)
9×6 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1       │ x2           │ x3           │ x4       │ x5      │ x6      │
│     │ Any      │ Any          │ Any          │ Any      │ Any     │ Any     │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ RegionID │ RegionName   │ StateName    │ SizeRank │ 2008-03 │ 2008-04 │
│ 2   │ 6181     │ New York     │ New York     │ 1        │ missing │ missing │
│ 3   │ 12447    │ Los Angeles  │ California   │ 2        │ 1446    │ 1705    │
│ 4   │ 39051    │ Houston      │ Texas        │ 3        │ 2926    │ 3121    │
│ 5   │ 17426    │ Chicago      │ Illinois     │ 4        │ 2910    │ 3022    │
│ 6   │ 6915     │ San Antonio  │ Texas        │ 5        │ 1479    │ 1529    │
│ 7   │ 13271    │ Philadelphia │ Pennsylvania │ 6        │ 1609    │ 1795    │
│ 8   │ 40326    │ Phoenix      │ Arizona      │ 7        │ 1310    │ 1519    │
│ 9   │ 18959    │ Las Vegas    │ Nevada       │ 8        │ 1618    │ 1856    │
```

Dataframe without Header:

```
julia> DataFrame(T[2:9,:])
8×6 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1    │ x2           │ x3           │ x4  │ x5      │ x6      │
│     │ Any   │ Any          │ Any          │ Any │ Any     │ Any     │
├─────┼───────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 6181  │ New York     │ New York     │ 1   │ missing │ missing │
│ 2   │ 12447 │ Los Angeles  │ California   │ 2   │ 1446    │ 1705    │
│ 3   │ 39051 │ Houston      │ Texas        │ 3   │ 2926    │ 3121    │
│ 4   │ 17426 │ Chicago      │ Illinois     │ 4   │ 2910    │ 3022    │
│ 5   │ 6915  │ San Antonio  │ Texas        │ 5   │ 1479    │ 1529    │
│ 6   │ 13271 │ Philadelphia │ Pennsylvania │ 6   │ 1609    │ 1795    │
│ 7   │ 40326 │ Phoenix      │ Arizona      │ 7   │ 1310    │ 1519    │
│ 8   │ 18959 │ Las Vegas    │ Nevada       │ 8   │ 1618    │ 1856    │
```

Throws error while creating with header:

```
julia> DataFrame(T[2:9,:],T[1,:])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching DataFrame(::Array{Any,2}, ::Array{Any,1})
Closest candidates are:
  DataFrame(::AbstractArray{T,2} where T) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:209
  DataFrame(::AbstractArray{T,2} where T, ::AbstractArray{Symbol,1}; makeunique) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:209
  DataFrame(::T; copycols) where T at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/other/tables.jl:23
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[19]:1
```

**Update1**

With reference to PaSTE's solution:

```
julia> DataFrame(T[2:end,:], convert(Vector{String},T[1,:]))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching DataFrame(::Array{Any,2}, ::Array{String,1})
Closest candidates are:
  DataFrame(::AbstractArray{T,2} where T) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:209
  DataFrame(::AbstractArray{T,2} where T, ::AbstractArray{Symbol,1}; makeunique) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:209
  DataFrame(::T; copycols) where T at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/DataFrames/yH0f6/src/other/tables.jl:23
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[19]:1
```

Please guide me in creating DataFrame from XLSX.readdata() object with header.

**Update2:**

I got it in trial and error method:

```
julia> df2=DataFrame(T[2:end,:], Symbol.(vec(T[1,:])))
8×6 DataFrame
│ Row │ RegionID │ RegionName   │ StateName    │ SizeRank │ 2008-03 │ 2008-04 │
│     │ Any      │ Any          │ Any          │ Any      │ Any     │ Any     │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 6181     │ New York     │ New York     │ 1        │ missing │ missing │
│ 2   │ 12447    │ Los Angeles  │ California   │ 2        │ 1446    │ 1705    │
│ 3   │ 39051    │ Houston      │ Texas        │ 3        │ 2926    │ 3121    │
│ 4   │ 17426    │ Chicago      │ Illinois     │ 4        │ 2910    │ 3022    │
│ 5   │ 6915     │ San Antonio  │ Texas        │ 5        │ 1479    │ 1529    │
│ 6   │ 13271    │ Philadelphia │ Pennsylvania │ 6        │ 1609    │ 1795    │
│ 7   │ 40326    │ Phoenix      │ Arizona      │ 7        │ 1310    │ 1519    │
│ 8   │ 18959    │ Las Vegas    │ Nevada       │ 8        │ 1618    │ 1856    │
```

Comment: Concerning your update: it looks like you are using an old version of the `DataFrames` package. Consider upgrading--the ability to use strings as column names in the constructor has been available since version 0.21.

Answer (score 1):

### Consider using `XLSX.readtable`

The easiest way to get XLSX.jl to read data as a table for DataFrames to parse is to use the [`XLSX.readtable`](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/api/#XLSX.readtable) method instead of `XLSX.readdata`. Using [an example `.xlsx` file](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/blob/master/data/Book1.xlsx) used for testing by the package:

```
XLSX.readtable("Book1.xlsx", # file name
               1,  # first sheet
)
```

Result:

```
(Any[Any[10.5, Dates.Date("2018-03-21"), Dates.Date("2018-03-21"), true, 1, "palavra1"], Any[21.2, Dates.Date("2018-03-22"), Dates.Date("2018-03-22"), false, 2, "palavra2"]], [:B2, :C2])
```

`XLSX.readtable` automatically reads the first non-empty row in the file as column labels.  It also skips empty columns at the left side of the worksheet automatically as well.  The documentation suggests how to read this into a `DataFrame`:

> the `...` operator will splat the tuple (data, column_labels) into the constructor of DataFrame.

That means we can do this:

```
df1 = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Book1.xlsx", 1)...)
```

Result:

```
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ B2          C2
     │ Any         Any
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 10.5        21.2
   2 │ 2018-03-21  2018-03-22
   3 │ 2018-03-21  2018-03-22
   4 │ true        false
   5 │ 1           2
   6 │ palavra1    palavra2
```

### Using `XLSX.readdata` instead

If you insist on using `XLSX.readdata`, you will have to manually convert the first row to a vector of Strings:

```
data = XLSX.readdata("Book1.xlsx", 1, "B2:C8")
df2 = DataFrame(data[2:end,:], convert(Vector{String}, data[1,:]))

df1 == df2  # true
```